# Python dir() function with variable arguments

Tags: python, dir

For fun/to practice python, I am trying to create a program that displays the contents of a module. Looks like this:

```
import sys
print "Here are all the functions in the sys module: "
print dir(sys)
function = raw_input("Pick a function to see: ")

cnt = True

while cnt:
        if function in dir(sys):
                print "You chose:", function
                cnt = False
        else:
                print "Invalid choice, please select again."
                cnt = True
print dir("sys." + function)
```

But every time, no matter what string the variable `function` is set to, the `dir("sys." + function)` call always defaults to the same output as `dir(string)` (or so I think!)

What is happening and is there a way for me to do this properly and get the output I really want (for example, the variable `function` is set to `stdin` and I get the output for `dir(sys.stdin)`)?

Comment: use `while cnt:` instead of `while cnt == True:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to retrieve the actual object from the module; use the [`getattr()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) for that:

```
print dir(getattr(sys, function))
```

`dir()` does not interpret the contents of the objects you pass to it; a string that happens to contain a value that corresponds to the name of a function in a module is not dereferenced for you.

Comment: @Pieters What senses have the words ``string`` and ``value`` in your sentence please ?

Comment: @eyquem: String: the `str` type in python. Value: the contents (characters) of the string.

Comment: @Pieters You mean, for string: **an object of type 'str'** ?

Comment: @eyquem So you meant: "an object of type 'str' that happens to contain a value that corresponds..." , am I right ?

Comment: Yes. Where is this going? We usually talk about strings, not about "an object of type `str`", because that's cumbersome and overly verbose.

Comment: @Pieters That may be the case in programming, but in general life, the word 'string' is used to designate a suite of letters. And, since programming is a part of general life, it may happen that even in a programming context, someone would use the word 'string' in this sense. Then I wanted to be sure of the sense you were giving to it in your sentence before I do a mistake

Comment: @Pieters Because it hits me that a Python object be said to "contain" a value, since a simple Python object is never a 'variable', in the sense of "a chunk of memory whose content can change". By 'simple Python object', I mean the immutable objects that are the base of all the objects in Python. - In my opinion, a Python object holds a value, it doesn't contain a value.

Answer (score 2):

```
f = getattr(sys, function) # get function object
help(f) # display help for the function
```

Note: `dir(f)` would return the same info for all functions with the same type.

Answer (score 1):

As dir works on objects, you need to get the object somehow from the name.

First option is to use getattr:

```
print dir(getattr(sys, function))
```

If you want to be more flexible (and are ready to take security risk), you can use eval:

```
print dir(eval('sys.' + function))
```